# Сократить или оптимизировать javascript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Новичок в javascript. Можно ли этот код оптимизировать или сократить в плане производительности.

```
if (id_roulette == 1)
{
    if (data == 10) data = 2
    if (data == 20) data = 6
    if (data == 35) data = 3
    if (data == 50) data = 4
    if (data == 75) data = 1
    if (data == 150) data = 5
    if (data == 250) data = 7
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML) >= 50)
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML) - 50;

    setTimeout(function(){$('#minusm').fadeIn('fast')},0);

    setTimeout(function(){$('#minusm').fadeOut('fast')},1000);
}

$('#roulette').removeAttr('class').addClass('number-' + data); 

setTimeout(function(){ ТЕСТ() },5200);

$.post('/test.php',{}, function(data) {
    if (parseInt(data)>=50)
    setTimeout(function(){$('.spinrollpage').fadeIn('fast')},6500);
})
```

Comment: данный код нагружает сервер _одним_ запросом `$.post('/test.php'` единственный способ сократить эту нагрузку - убрать этот вызов, тогда сервер вообще не будет нагружаться

Comment: а что делает `ТЕСТ()` ? - проблема с загрузкой сервера не может вызываться из него? потому как, правильно заметил Grundy, в представленном коде нагрузку на сервер создает только `post` запрос.

Comment: тавтологии нету в коде? Будет ли он нагружать клиент если сервер не нагружает?  test.php подключает к БД и выбирает и записывает информацию и в переменную.

Comment: Вам мягко намекают, что это javascript и если вы его используете не на сервере (nodejs), то он нагружает клиента (выполняется в браузере) и никак не трогает сервер кроме как, когда формируется страница, и когда вы делаете пост запрос из javascript.  По этому на ваш текущий вопрос никто не даст ответа

Comment: $ - мягко намекает что это клиент

Comment: Ладно, тогда вопрос в другом. Можно ли его сократить чтобы нагрузка на клиент стала меньше?

Comment: @papiroca https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery

Comment: @Bookin за информацию о серверном $ спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну я бы как минимум сделал следующее:

заменил бы

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML) >= 50)
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML) - 50;
```

на

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var elemInnerHTML = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
if (elemInnerHTML >= 50) {
    elem.innerHTML = elemInnerHTML - 50;
}
```

так как в вашем варианте у `document` 3 раза вызывается `getElementById`, 3 раза читается свойство `innerHTML` и 2 раза преобразуется с помощью `parseInt`.

и возможно сменил бы if на switch, это могло бы быть полезно при обнаружении неожидаемого значения data.

```
switch (data) {
    case 10: data = 2; break;
    case 20: data = 6; break;
    case 35: data = 3; break;
    case 50: data = 4; break;
    case 75: data = 1; break;
    case 150: data = 5; break;
    case 250: data = 7; break;
    default: console.warn('Unexpected data value: ' + data );
};
```

Comment: switch и if вообще не нужны, даже если надо обрабатывать ошибки: `data={10:2,20:6,35:3,50:4,75:1,150:5,250:7}[data] || (console.warn('error data '+data),data);`

Comment: @Mike, я лишь старался написать понятную конструкцию для уровня владения `js`, который автор обозначил в вопросе. Ваш вариант беспорно лучше.

Comment: @Mike а вы можете подсказать, как ваш код работает? Просто я тоже "учащийся" и мне очень интересно как этот код выполняется по шагам (по крайней мере до || )

Comment: @alexoander в фигурных скобках объявляется объект. Объекты работают так же, как в других языках ассоциативные массивы, т.е. массивы адресуемые конкретными ключами. `{10:2}` 10-ключ, 2-значение. дальше мы берем из этого конкретный элемент `[data]`. более длинно можно было бы написать `var obj={10:2,...};  data=obj[data]`. если подходящего индекса в объекте нет - то будет undefined сработает `||` выдаст ошибку и при этом сработает оператор запятая, которая вернет последнее значение списка т.е. саму data. это для того что бы data не стала undefined если она не правильная

Comment: @Mike Благодарю ! Теперь стало понятно